# Prime Numbers Implementation

Tags: c++

I started to learn algorithms and C++,and I thought to write a program which will check prime numbers.I know it's awful code,and I'm going to improve that,but firstly i need to know the problem.

So let's check for example number=25.When i=5,25%5=0,so why it gives me 'Yes'?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int number;
cin >> number;
if (number < 2) {
    cout << "No";
}
else if (number == 2) {
    cout << "Yes";
}
else {
    for (int i = 2; i<number; i++) {
        if ((number % i) != 0) {
            cout << "Yes";
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

======================================================================

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int number;
cin >> number;
if (number < 2) {
    cout << "No";
}
else if (number == 2) {
    cout << "Yes";
}
    for (int i = 2; ((i < number) && (number%i==0)); i++) {
        cout << "No";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Also I tried something like this above(but I'm not sure about this),but the problem with odd numbers with few dividers is still the same.

Comment: The condition `(number % i) != 0` is satisfied multiple times .

Comment: Any particular reason you're not printing the factors you're testing to validate your assumption that `i==5` is reporting `Yes` incorrectly? `cout << "Yes : " << i << '\n';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through the following code in detail, assuming that `number == 25`:

```
for (int i = 2; i<number; i++) {
    if ((number % i) != 0) {
        cout << "Yes";
    }
}
```

---

In the first run of the loop, we have `number == 25` and `i == 2`.

```
if ((number % i) != 0) {
    cout << "Yes";
}
```

Evaluating `number % i` yields `25 % 2`, which is `1`. `1` is not equal to `0`, so the body of the `if`-statement is executed, and prints `"Yes"` to that standard output.

---

Clearly, there are many numbers that don't evenly divide `25`. To test whether `25` is prime, we need to test that *none* of the numbers evenly divide `25`.

Here's one way you could do this:

```
for (int i = 2; i<number; i++) {
    // if `i` evenly divides `number`,
    if ((number % i) == 0) {
        // it is certainly not prime
        cout << "No";
        // stop searching and return
        return 0;
    }
}
// Otherwise, if this point is reached, nothing divides `number`
// Thus, `number` must be prime
cout << "Yes";
```

---

With any good C++ compiler, you should be able to debug your program interactively, and step through the code line-by-line, watching values change, and seeing where your intuition and your code don't match. Debugging is a very valuable part of programming. How exactly it's done varies with your compiler, but if you simply google "how to debug C++ using [my compiler]", I expect you'll find many helpful resources.

Comment: Addendum for future askers : You may find researching prime number sieving algorithms a helpful alternative solution.